# Unable to import access database to SQL Server - unrecognized database format '.mdb'. (microsoft jet database engine)

Tags: database, sql-server, microsoft-access

I am trying to import .mdb (Access database file) to SQL Server.

[image: SQL Server MDB file (Access database) import wizard - Unrecognized database format (Microsoft Jet Database Engine)]

Adding the sys-admin privilege username and password also does not help and gives an error - not a valid account name or password.

Answer (score 0):

The file was corrupted as the file was changed from .mdb to .txt and then again .mdb.
A fresh copy of .mdb helped me to restore the database.

A thing to remember, do not save the database with a password, always save the database without passwords, it allows a smooth restore.